# Export Word Document to PDF With Markup

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use VBA to compare two word documents, then export the redline to a PDF.

My comparison code generates a .docx correctly, but when I export this to PDF using the below code, it doesn't show the changes inline and instead just shows the latest document.

```
wDoc1.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=saveFolder & "Redline.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

I've played with these parameters and it still doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to make Word export the markup to a PDF? Thanks.

Comment: The CompareDocuments  method returns a document which contains the redline comparison.  So you should have code along the lines of my_redline_doc = CompareDocuments............  You would then save the my_redline_doc.  Is wDoc1 the redline doc?

Comment: Yes, wDoc1 is the redline do. If you save wDoc1 as a docx, you get the redline correctly, if you export it then it doesn't show the markup.

Comment: It works fine for me. I get a pdf containing the redline document. Try using the macro recorder and check what you get against your code.

Comment: I used the macro recorder and it's working perfectly now. I assume it's this part: Item:=wdExportDocumentWithMarkup. Thanks so much for your help.